# Pigeonholing for Slopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

I am reading arxiv from Rudnev and Stevens https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.11145.pdf. I am stucked in the proof of proposition 1. First, they prove we cannot have $Q_B\leq N^2\tau^2/8$ for at least $50$% of bunches. Why after that they assume $Q_B\geq N^2\tau^2/4$ for at least half of the bunches and not $Q_B\geq N^2\tau^2/8$? And how to use pigeonhole principle in the slopes to get at least $N/16$ values of $\lambda_3$?